# Certification Test Tool 1.2 for Azure WinRM cannot complete the operation

Tags: powershell, azure, connection, virtual-machine

I'm currently trying to connect to my Virtual Machine with **Windows Server 2012** Datacenter and connect to it via **Certification Test Tool 1.2 for Azure**. And always getting this error:

> Connecting to remote server xyz-vm.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
>   failed with the following error message: **WinRM cannot complete the
>   operation**. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the
>   computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception
>   for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer.
>   By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits
>   access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I guess the tool is using PSRemot so I checked that:

- "winrm" is running.
- "PS Remoting" is enabled in the firewall.
- Port 5985 and 5986 are in the network security group in Azure and at the local VM Firewall allowed.

I tested the connection via Test-WSMan and I got a connection:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtXCX.png). But the connection with the Certification Test Tool  still failed.

Even after turning the Firewall of the VM completely of, it didn't work

Thank you for your Help

Comment: You could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/winrm) if you could create a new VM.

Comment: For a existing VM, you also check this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/). You need create a self-certificate and enable https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Shengbao Shui - MSFT

For a existing VM, you also check this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/). You need create a self-certificate and enable https.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run in cmd on the Virtual Machine `netsh winhttp show proxy`

If this shows port 8080 could you then run `netsh winhttp reset proxy`

Comment: The Result was `Direct access (no proxy server)`